# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: node.js

I get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null" when I try to run my discord bot command code. This has worked perfectly for a year and all of a sudden it doesnt work.

The usage for the code is to check if a member has a role and then either add or remove the role.

code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
if ((message.content === prefix + 'cs') || (message.content === prefix + 'CS')) {
        if (message.member.roles.has('371060297773088768')) {
            message.member.removeRole('371060297773088768')
                .then(() => message.reply('Counter-Strike role removed!'));
        } else {
            message.member.addRole('371060297773088768')
                .then(() => message.reply('Counter-Strike role added!'));
        }
    }
});
```

PS: This bot is only ment for one server, hence why I dont make it clear which guild the message is from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `message.member.roles.cache.has('371060297773088768')`

```
client.on('message', message => {
if ((message.content === prefix + 'cs') || (message.content === prefix + 'CS')) {
        if (message.member.roles.cache.has('371060297773088768')) {
            message.member.removeRole('371060297773088768')
                .then(() => message.reply('Counter-Strike role removed!'));
        } else {
            message.member.addRole('371060297773088768')
                .then(() => message.reply('Counter-Strike role added!'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: When added I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined"

Comment: Seems like I had a outdated version. Sorry about that. The code works